# How to align buttons horizontal to the text in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have made a few `div` tags which are dynamically created using javascript and each `div` consists of 3 `<p>` and 2 `<button>`. Now I want to align these buttons which are created dynamically side by side to the text and not below the text.
See screenshot I have shown where the buttons should be placed.

app.js:

```
contactList.innerHTML = '';
        for(var i in array) {
                    var id = i;
                    contactList.innerHTML +=
                       `
                        <li>
                        <div class="contactDetail">
                        <p>Name: ${array[i].fullName}</p>
                        <p>Number: ${array[i].number}</p>
                        <p>Group: ${array[i].group}</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="editContact(${id})">Edit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteMe(${id})">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                        `;
        }
```

screenshot I have shown were the final position of buttons should be using arrows:

[image]

Comment: .btn {display: block;}

Comment: @jilykate How can I do that dynamically ?

Comment: You don't need to care about if it is dynamic created or not. This only affect when you do event binding in js, it won't affect what you specify in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the text and the buttons in divs and float them.

```css
.contactDetail::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.contactDetail__text {
  float: left;
}

.contactDetail__actions {
  float: right;
}

.contactDetail__actions .btn {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="contactDetail">
      <div class="contactDetail__text">
        <p>Name: ${array[i].fullName}</p>
        <p>Number: ${array[i].number}</p>
        <p>Group: ${array[i].group}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="contactDetail__actions">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="editContact(${id})">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteMe(${id})">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="contactDetail">
      <div class="contactDetail__text">
        <p>Name: ${array[i].fullName}</p>
        <p>Number: ${array[i].number}</p>
        <p>Group: ${array[i].group}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="contactDetail__actions">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="editContact(${id})">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteMe(${id})">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```